# JUnit and jms - events fired are not consumed in the middle of test

Tags: spring, junit, activemq-classic, spring-jms

We are using spring with junit , jms (activemq) and mySql.

We would like to create some junit tests that after their executions the db will rollback.

In order to achieve that we are using the @Transactional annotation for each tests.

Problem is, one of our tests is calling a service that sends a jms message, (in the middle of the test) the thing is the event is being consumed only after the tests ends (end of transaction maybe?) 
thats why the assertion in the end of the test fails.

any ideas why the event is not being consumed right away (p.s we tried to use sleep in order to let the event be consumed, its not working)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is not a unit test ... that's fine ... There are 2 reasons message is not consumed:

1. The transaction in which the message is sent is not committed. Due to this the lock on the message on the server side is not released.
2. There is a timing issue and the test ends too soon and doesn't wait got the callback.

Answer (score 0):

That's the whole point of transactions. The message is not available for consumption until the transaction commits (otherwise how could you roll it back if someone's already seen it?). You can do the send in a new transaction (Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) if you don't want the send to be part of the encompassing transaction.